# Check if DateTimePicker calendar is dropped down

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

How does one go about checking if a `DateTimePicker` Control is currently displaying its calendar?

By comparison, checking a `ComboBox` to see if its drop down list is displayed is so simple:

```
if (comboBox.DroppedDown)
  //do something
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the same result for a `DateTimePicker`'s calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see one either. 
You could create a bool to indicate whether it's dropped down.

Set it to `true` in the `DropDown` event.

> Occurs when the drop-down calendar is shown.

Set it to `false` in the `CloseUp` event.

> Occurs when the drop-down calendar is dismissed and disappears.

---

I noticed the snippet you typed in your question:

```
if (comboBox.DroppedDown)
    //do something
```

If you're just trying to do something when the calendar is displayed, put your code in (or call your code from) the `DropDown` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try implenting your self

```
private void DateTimePicker1_DropDown(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
  myVar = true; 
}

private void DateTimePicker1_CloseUp(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
  myVar = false;    
}
```